# revoke vs deny : what is the difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration, sqlcommand, sql-revoke

What is the difference between the [DENY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx) and [REVOKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187719.aspx) commands in SQL Server?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Revoke is the opposite of a Grant (at least in as much as Grant adds an access rule and Revoke Removes an access Rule) While somewhat counter-intuative Deny also adds an access rule (which of course can be removed with a Revoke).

If I grant the sales group access I can later revoke it.

However I could also deny you access, and even through you're in the sales group you'll not have access.

Comment: Revoke is not the opposite of grant.  Deny is the opposite of grant.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by 'opposite'. Revoke is the operation that will restore the state of an access list (that previously had no relevant rule) to what it was before a grant.

Comment: As a programmer I understand it in the following way: **GRANT** is `+= Some (Read/Write/Manipulate) Rule`, **DENY** is `+= Some (Read/Write/Manipulate prohibition) Rule`, **REVOKE** is `-= Some (Any type) Rule`.

Answer (score 26):

Each object has a list of rules `DENY`ing and `GRANT`ing access.

`REVOKE` is an operation that removes a rule from the list of access rules.

Comment: Can I revoke DENY rule by REVOKE operation?

Comment: Yes, if you want to reverse the action of a DENY you ReREVOKE it (as counter-intuative as that may sound).  Under the covers think of both GRANT and DENY as insert to the sysproctects and REVOKE is a delete from the sysprotects.

Comment: @demas: yes, for example: `deny select on TestTable to TestUser; revoke select on TestTable to TestUser`

Comment: Another one questions :) If I granted access to schema, can I revoke access to one table from this schema or the use DENY is the only one way to do it

Comment: *"REVOKE is an operation that removes a rule from the list of access rules."* Which rule is removed? The most recently added?

Comment: What do you mean by object here?

Answer (score 12):

`REVOKE` removes access that has been `GRANT`ed. `DENY` explicitly rejects, taking precedence over `GRANT`s.

To the last point, if someone is part of the `db_denydatawriter` role, but you `GRANT INSERT to` them, the `DENY` will override that `GRANT` and they will be unable to `INSERT`.

Comment: I am a bit new to Sql Server so i have the following question...Why do i have to DENY or REVOKE? Can't I simply remove the GRANT for that Insert action?

Comment: @dimmik A massive bump, I realise, but revoking *is* what you do to "simply remove the GRANT from that Insert action".

Answer (score 1):

1. Granting Permission means that a user can access the object
2. Denying permission overrides a granted permission
3. Revoking a permission removes the permission that has been assigned, regardless of whether it was a denied permission or a granted permission